# Are there any formal, fully fleshed-out mathematical models that capture the Kuhnian idea of scientific revolutions?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, kuhn, philosophy-of-social-sciences

I searched for a while and wasn't able to find any attempts of [formal mathematical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_modelling). And thus the question.

If you know of any formal mathematical work that is related but not on the exact same topic, please also bring them up. Thanks!

Comment: See [Joseph Sneed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_D._Sneed) and [Wolfgang Stegmuller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Stegm%C3%BCller)

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Tag and link added.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks. I believe you are referring to structuralism? If you have to choose one or a few specific paper or book references (with mathematical modeling), can you tell me what you would choose? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

As far as I know, the main preoccupation of science philosophers adjacent to [The Structure of Scientific Revolutions (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/thomas-kuhn/#ReceDeve) is not [model-theoretic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) models of the social forces at play, but rather the [structure of scientific theories (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structure-scientific-theories/). If there are [statistical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model) of [Kuhn's theory proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions), then they'll more likely be found in research related to the [social aspects of scientific knowledge (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-knowledge-social/). The WP article ["sociology of scientific knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociology_of_scientific_knowledge)" also has links. I think a good start would be the [PhilPapers Article: "The Structure of Scientific Revolutions"](https://philpapers.org/rec/KUHTSO-3). From there you can look at related links and the categories of PhilPaper to hunt down statistics (if they exist). Another place to search would be [here (ScienceDirect.com)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=structures%20of%20scientific%20revolution).

#### Post Script

In regards to the finding ideas derivative of [Robert Merton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_K._Merton), your best bet is to become familiar with and ask the question of others [sociology journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sociology_journals). The best way to find such people might be to read up on both the [International Sociological Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Sociological_Association) whose [website is here](https://www.isa-sociology.org) and the [American Sociological Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sociological_Association) whose [website is here](https://www.asanet.org/).
StackExchange options don't seem to include a forum related to your pursuit but you might come across references to Merton in the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), seeing as he is pivotal to the founding of a scientific discipline.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, indeed, I am looking for the social structure. I guess a related question is whether anyone following the Mertonian “sociology of science” attempted to do any formal mathematical modeling. Of course, perhaps I should ask this in a different forum?

Comment: @JLi Added a PS.

Answer (score 0):

Model theory is a theory of formal logic. And it's in within mathematics that this notion is useful. For example, the Eilenberg-Moore category of models of the jet comonad is the category of PDEs.

The paucity of work using formal logic/model theory to model scientific theories should indicate that most model theorists do not think it is the right language to theorise about theories a la Kuhn or a la anybody else.

Kuhnian theory transparently uses the language of Marxism to model theory change. In the opinion of at least one historian and philosopher of science, Mario Bunge, his work was banal and he didn't know very much of the history of science.

Comment: Thanks Mozibur. I’m less looking for models of theories, but models of the social process that produce and evaluate such theories.

Comment: @J Li: This is what I was talking about. A scientific theory can be a theory like natural selection or models of the social process that produce or evaluate such theories. One model of such a social process is evolutionary game theory, and the SEP finds their explanatory power 'crude' and they charge them with 'irrelevance'. This is more or less what I was saying above about such models.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Thanks!